# Runtime error in creating beans. java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javabeans, applicationcontext

I am getting an error in runtime of my spring 5 application. It is working fine in debug mode in eclipse but throwing the errors while creating bean from the application context. Below I have shared the error log. I have rebuild the jar many times and changed the dependencies in manifest file but still the same error while runtime. Please advice.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
 h name 'LIQBeanFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/LoanIQ/Server/sdk-post/QNB_
 GL_V92_PROD_Encr.jar!/beanRefFactory.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor fa
 iled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicati
 onContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework
.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LiqTransact
 ionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initializat
 ion of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver
 class org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxy
 Creator does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abst
 ract postProcessPropertyValues(Lorg/springframework/beans/PropertyValues;[Ljava/
 beans/PropertyDescriptor;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframewo
 rk/beans/PropertyValues; of interface org.springframework.beans.factory.config.I
 nstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor.
```

Comment: Please add the code for `LIQBeanFactory` and `LiqTransactionManager`

Comment: LiqTransactionManager is a bean id in applicationcontext.xml <bean id="LiqTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="LIQJobDataSource" />
 </bean>

Comment: When you are running the jar and getting this error, is it from outside the IDE?

If so, I would guess that the source of your issue is that your jar does not actually contain these runtime dependencies. A useful trick is to open up the jar with `jar -xvf <jar-file-path>` and check if the required classes are actually there.

If it is not there, then you'll need to provide more details about your jar build process to receive help.